# IIS http to https redirect rule works for browsers but breaks for API calls (returns a 401)

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, http-redirect, http-status-code-401

I want users accessing my secure site (setup with Windows Authentication) to always use `https`.  But knowing many of them inadvertently bookmarked `http` urls I decided to leave `http` on and instead use an `http` to `https` redirect.

Thus I installed https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite and setup this rule:

```
       <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="(.*)" />
           <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
```

Everything was fine for my web browser users, until other users complained their API calls from their scripts no longer work. Instead they are getting a 401 unauthorized:

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
Server Error

401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

I've verified that the credentials are correct, and I've verified when they change their scripts to use `https` everything works fine.  Furthermore, if they leave their scripts as `http` and I disable the `http` to `https` redirect, their scripts work fine.

So how do I configure my server to properly redirect these api calls from `http` to `https` without causing a 401 unauthorized?

Or is this instead an issue with the script?

Comment: Seems like this is the same issue, but for apache: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239033/strange-401-error-appears-for-some-urls-when-using-htaccess-to-redirect-http-to .  I'm using IIS and I'm not sure how to recreate the solution for IIS with URL Rewrite

Comment: You don't even know what kind of 401 you hit, so stop guessing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Failed Request Tracing is commonly used in this case. Run it and see what you find out.